# pip install -e: new library needed: how to get them

Tags: python, dependencies, pip

I installed a library "editable" with "pip install -e".

The library has updated the setup.py and new dependencies (install_requires=...) are required.

What should I do, to fetch the new dependencies?

I could install them manually. But an automatic resolve like on "pip install" would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `upgrade` option:

```
$ pip install -h
...
-U, --upgrade                Upgrade all packages to the newest available version
```

So: `pip install -U editable`